# Not sure how to deal with overlapping UI

Tags: unity

[image: This is my issue here]

As shown above, that is the issue I am faced with, tbh I am unsure how to fix it, I have tried and its coming to a point where I am drawing blank. I am quite newbie when it comes to this.

So what I have now is multiple canvas each one displaying the name of the part that it is linked to and when the part moves so does the UI with it, the problem I have is that some parts dont move and therefore creating the issue of UI clustering together, so I need to move the UI rather than the parts.

What I have tried is OnTriggerEnter and adding a box collider/rigidbody to the canvas and tried to move the UI when they collided but I couldnt get that to work, probably down to me.

```
if (gameObject.tag == "car")
    {

        //get the gameObjects name that canvas is attached to
        canvasName.text = gameObject.name;

        newPos = mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(this.transform.position);

        //set the position of the UI
        newPos.x = transform.position.x;
        newPos.y = transform.position.y + 7f;
        newPos.z = transform.position.z;

        //canvas position
        if (_canvas != null)
        {
            _canvas.transform.position = newPos;

        }
```

That is the code that I am using to attach the UI to the part. I was hoping to try something along the lines, but then again I am clueless.

if collision is detected, newPos.y = newPos + 2f; etc...

So any help would be appreciated. Apologies if that was explained bad.

Comment: have you tried applying a bounding sphere and letting the physics engine deal with it? if you make your reference line a spring, then when the objects are pulled close together, they'll bump into each other and drift up or down based on the spring settings.

Comment: When I was working on a hololens application I did something similar: I found the text's bounding box (as represented in screen space), checked it against every other text. If something was overlapping, I'd nudge the text that was "farther away" from the camera around until it no longer overlapped. You can see what I had working [over on this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/109662/103141) where I was asking for some input on good rules of placement (which may also help your situation).

Comment: "but I couldnt get that to work," But what is the problem, either GUI is not moving or else

Comment: Thanks Stephan, Dracos18s! I will have a look at these now and see what solution I can come up with. Mohammad Faizan Khan apologies if the question wasn't written well, but the issue is not with moving, its with overlapping UI as stated in the title. What I couldnt get to work was collisions using OnTriggerEnter.